# Cannot destructure property .... as undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, e-commerce, forgot-password

the page explodes and in the console I have these errors:

How can I solve this problem, be able to view the form to enter the email;

The page is blank and these are the errors: [image]

I solved this problem, it now functions like the photo attached:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably because the value of sentEmailStatus it's undefined when the component renders, during the first rendering.

If you want avoid this behaviour, you can change your destructuring:

```
  const { loading: loadingStatus, error: errorStatus, message: messageStatus } = sentEmailStatus || {};
```

This is called Short-circuit evaluation. You can check it there [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation)